# Insert HTML Tags in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to insert HTML tags in `ng-options`, so when the document's rendered the options have icons before the text.

HTML:

```
<select chosen id="receive-country-selection" ng-model="current.RecipientCountry" ng-change="selectRecipientCountry(current.RecipientCountry)" ng-options="x.Name.toLowerCase() for x in data.RecipientCountries"  >
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Needs to be rendered to something like:

```
<select chosen id="receive-country-selection" ng-model="current.RecipientCountry" ng-change="selectRecipientCountry(current.RecipientCountry)" ng-options="x.Name.toLowerCase() for x in data.RecipientCountries"  >
    <option>
       <span class="flag-sprite-container">
           <svg class="flag-sprite">
               <use xlink:href="someUrl"></use>
           </svg>
       </span>
       some text
    </option>
</select>
```

I'd like to know if there's a non-jQuery option to do this.

Additional info: I'm using jQuery Chosen which copies `select` to `ul` and `option` to `li`.

Answer (score 0):

The option tag only supports text.  You can probably find other implementations using div sections that behaves like a drop down.  I know twitter has a library called typeahead that has this sort of behavior.  There are many other such libraries.

Comment: jQuery Chosen actually translates option tags to underscored list items, so that's partially why I'm using it